# Is it possible add icon in bootstrap nav tabs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is sample code.

Is it possible add icon in bootstrap nav tabs like below picture.

[image]

I want to add number icon in nav tabs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/md62fn96/3/)**

You would do this with a [badge](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges),

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="badge">140</span></a></li>
```

and a little bit of CSS

```
.nav-tabs .badge{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Insert your badge and position is relative to the container like this:

```css
.count-badge {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      <span class="count-badge badge">140</span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible in multiple ways. Bootstrap has [badges](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges) that would be an elegant solution.

```
<span class="badge">140</span>
```

Comment: I suppose you suggest for me to do the complete thing...with CSS and all?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: Good point. But it's just sample code above...i'll work something out

Comment: I've noticed a lot of this too, it's not good enough to give the functionality many OP's expect you to do all the work for them, sad.